# Howto get Dataproperty inherited from superclass

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owl-api, reasoning

I am working on my ontology using owlapi and java, but I cant find a solution in such a case:

Here I have a class structure such as:

- Electronics

  - Radio

    - Handy

I created individuals to these classes having the same name as their class. As Electronics class has an individual named electronics.

- Class: **Electronics**

  Equivalent to:  **keyword some {"electronics"}**.
- Class: **Handy**

  Dataproperty:  **keyword**

  Data property value: **"handy"**, type:string

I use Hermit to search for individuals as **keyword some {"electronics","handy"}**.

I get the correct individuals as electronics and handy.

When I want to list the dataproperty **keyword** values of individuals in my Java code I cannot get keyword value of electronics.
Result is as follows:

- Individual: **electronics** and **keyword: null**
- Individual: **handy** and **keyword: "handy"**   (It must be "electronics" and "handy", but I can not list the keyword value "electronics" for handy individual)

How can I get dataproperty value of electronics class and how can I count matching keywords.

**I want to display my query results as:**

- Individual: **electronics**,  keyword:"**electronics**", matching keyword **count:1**
- Individual:**handy**, keyword {**"electronics","handy"**}, matching keyword **count:2**

Thank you.

Here is my ontology:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Ontology xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/2015/ipek_ontology" ontologyIRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/2015/ipek_ontology">
<Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
<Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
<Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>    
<Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
<Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
<Declaration>
<Class IRI="#Electronics"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<Class IRI="#Handy"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<Class IRI="#Radio"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<DataProperty IRI="#GTIP_number"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<DataProperty IRI="#Keyword"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#Electronics"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#handy"/>
</Declaration>
<Declaration>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#radio"/>
</Declaration>
<EquivalentClasses>
<Class IRI="#Electronics"/>
<DataHasValue>
<DataProperty IRI="#Keyword"/>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">electronics</Literal>
</DataHasValue>
</EquivalentClasses>
<SubClassOf>
<Class IRI="#Handy"/>
<Class IRI="#Radio"/>
</SubClassOf>
<SubClassOf>
<Class IRI="#Radio"/>
<Class IRI="#Electronics"/>
</SubClassOf>
<ClassAssertion>
<Class IRI="#Electronics"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#Electronics"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<ClassAssertion>
<Class IRI="#Handy"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#handy"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<ClassAssertion>
<Class IRI="#Radio"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#radio"/>
</ClassAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataProperty IRI="#GTIP_number"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#Electronics"/>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">20.12 </Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataProperty IRI="#GTIP_number"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#handy"/>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">20.12.15.47</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataProperty IRI="#Keyword"/>
<NamedIndividual IRI="#handy"/>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">handy</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataProperty IRI="#GTIP_number"/><NamedIndividual IRI="#radio"/>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">20.12.15</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
<DataPropertyRange>
<DataProperty IRI="#GTIP_number"/>
<Datatype abbreviatedIRI="xsd:string"/>
</DataPropertyRange>
<DataPropertyRange>
<DataProperty IRI="#Keyword"/>
<Datatype abbreviatedIRI="xsd:string"/>
</DataPropertyRange>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/><IRI>#Electronics</IRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">Electronics</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
<IRI>#GTIP_number</IRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">GTIP_number</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="owl:deprecated"/><IRI>#Keyword</IRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">Keyword</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/><IRI>#Radio</IRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">Radio</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:comment"/>
<AbbreviatedIRI>rdfs:isDefinedBy</AbbreviatedIRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Product Code</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:isDefinedBy"/>
<AbbreviatedIRI>rdfs:isDefinedBy</AbbreviatedIRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#Name">Funda</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationAssertion>
<AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="owl:versionInfo"/>
<AbbreviatedIRI>rdfs:isDefinedBy</AbbreviatedIRI>
<Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">1.0</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
</Ontology>
<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net
```

-->`And the following is some piece of my code in java, I compare keyword values of indivduals with KeywordArray elements:

```
public static String RankEntity(OWLEntity entity){   //rank results
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    OWLDataProperty p = factory.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(base + "keyword"));
    String keyword="";
    Set<OWLNamedIndividual> result = entity.getIndividualsInSignature();  
    for (OWLNamedIndividual owlNamedIndividual : result) {
        for (OWLClassExpression eclass:EntitySearcher.getTypes(owlNamedIndividual, ontology)){
                    for (OWLLiteral lit: EntitySearcher .getDataPropertyValues(owlNamedIndividual,p,ontology)){
                    for (int j=0;j<KeywordArray.length;j++){
                        if (KeywordArray[j]!=null){
                            if(lit.getLiteral().equals(KeywordArray[j]))
                                {
                                    if (keyword=="")
                                        keyword+= " " + KeywordArray[j];
                                    else
                                        keyword+= ", " + KeywordArray[j];

                                    erank++;
                                }
                        }

                }       
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Rank: [ " + erank + " ]\t " +
                "keywords: [ " + keyword + " ]");
    }
    return ("Rank: [ " + erank + " ]\t " +
            "Keywords: [ " + keyword + " ]");
}'
```

Comment: You'll need to show your actual code.  It's not clear what you mean when you say "When I want to display the keywords values of these individuals I cannot get keyword value of electronics".  Do you want to do this in Java code?  In Protege?  In something else?

Comment: Also, please share the ontology

Comment: I detailed my problem, showed a piece of my code and shared my ontology. I use Java, and I construct my ontology on Protege 4.3, I use OWL API 3.4.2

Comment: You need an OWL reasoner to get inferred information. `EntitySearcher` does only work on asserted axioms.

Comment: I use Hermit for reasoning.

Comment: When you use `ÈntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues` NO reasoner is used. Why do you think so?

Comment: ok I will have a try on reasoners, thank you for your comment.

Comment: I also have another question. Can I use "NOT" with data properties. For example can I query **not(keyword some {"electronic"})** . Is there a solution to do it. I want to get is entities not having electronics as keyword without negativadataproperty assertion.

Comment: Hİ, I had many trials using Hermit, ı can get individuals related to class description as **keyword some {"electronics"}** but I can not diplay **inferred value** that is string "electronics". Can any one send a sample code in Java?

Comment: Theres' confusion here. EntitySearcher is not available in OWLAPI 3.x, only in version 4 and 5.

Comment: You are right, I checked my libraries from Java and it is 4.1.0. Does anyone has a code sample, or has an idea about getting dataproperty value inferring from an equalclass description, as I mentioned above??? I try to count matching dataproperty values, and also display the values for each class but I can't.