# Returning DataSomeValues of an Equal Class

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api, reasoning

I try to return DataSomeValuesFrom values of an Equal class.
Some piece of my ontology is as follows:

As you can see I have **Electronics** class, it has a data property named **Keyword**, and definition of my class is  **Keyword some {"electronics","equipment"}** .

As a summary:

- **Class:** Electronics
- **Dataproperty:** Keyword
- **Equivalent_to:** Keyword some {"electronics","equipment"}

`<EquivalentClasses>
    <Class IRI="#Electronics"/>
    <DataSomeValuesFrom>
    <DataProperty IRI="#Keyword"/>
    <DataOneOf>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">electronics</Literal>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#PlainLiteral">equipment</Literal>
    </DataOneOf>
    </DataSomeValuesFrom>
</EquivalentClasses>`

I use Java, OWL API 4.1.0 and Hermit 1.3.8 for development,

When I query for **Keyword some {"electronics"}**, I want to list dataproperty values as **"electronics"** and **"equipment"**.

The similar piece of code, in the following, is for returning the dataproperty values, I can return dataproperty (named **keyword**) value when I directly add it to an individual as a dataproperty from Protege, but it does not work for equal classes that it is keyword value is given in class definition.
Is there a possible solution for this problem? How can I retrieve DataSomeValuesFrom literal of an equal class, and how can display it? If possible can you show me some piece of code.

Thank you.

```
`    Collection<OWLLiteral> l1 =EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(owlNamedIndividual,p,ontology);
        for (OWLLiteral elem : l1) {
                if (elem.getLiteral().equals(GTIP_Search.ArrSiz[s]))
                      return elem.getLiteral();
        }`
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821246/howto-get-dataproperty-inherited-from-superclass.

Comment: And as I already said, you have to use a reasoner and not the `EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues` method which only works on asserted axioms in the ontology.